# Where custom code is stored?

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-addin

I have been given a SharePoint 2013 system (never used SharePoint...), they've got a really complicated process that doesn't work as intended (it never did).

All I am trying to do at this point is find where the binaries are stored so I can upload a new version with some additional debugging (I've got a .sln that compiles the project).

I have found the .aspx file that runs the code via

`__doPostBack('GenerateAppNameAssessment', '');`

What I am trying to find is where `GenerateAppNameAssessment` is stored/defined so I can eventually find the binary.

Using deploy via Visual Studio doesn't do anything (unless I have to restart the IIS/SharePoint server? Again, never used SharePoint...)

Comment: So your are  going to spend days of work where a contractor can do it in 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

The DLL's can be deployed either in:

- The GAC (for SharePoint 2013 - .net 4.0 - this is located in C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly)
- The IIS web application's BIN folder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some .js file where this method is written. Do one thing..Go the ,aspx page and press F12.. Select Sources in developer tool and search the method name in .js files which will in folder like Style library or Site Assest or it can be any other name. Try out this and let know.

Comment: __doPostBack is a ASP function that just creates a form and submits it, the code for serving `GenerateAppNameAssessment` is what I am looking for